# Grouping by Polygons in MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, polygon, geospatial

I have a json containing the polygons that represent the delimiters of all cities (78 in total) in a country. For example:

```
{
    "City1":[
        [-67.103276,18.513426],
        [-67.10339411502086,18.514532657212502],
        [-67.093752,18.515757],
        [-67.05297606966441,18.512073045833525]
    ],
    "City2":[
        [-67.16901339052771,18.472154288860388],
        [-67.169016,18.478488],
        [-67.138249,18.507776],
        [-67.12906260088943,18.510642646697203],
        [-67.125655,18.511706]
    ],
    "City3":[
        [-66.034932,18.333452],
        [-66.03494,18.332214],
        [-66.035911,18.328084],
        [-66.035731,18.31961],
        [-66.036859,18.318627]
    ],
    ...
}
```

I'm using the ruby driver for MongoDB. The database contains a collection of points (indexed as 2dsphere). I need to calculate the total count of points inside a city. The result should say, for example, "City1 contains 56 points, City2 contains 40 points, City3 contains 100 points".

This is code that I'm using to find the points inside a single polygon, and setting a date range from_date to end_date (since the points have a date property)

```
polygon = [[-67.103276,18.513426],[-67.10339411502086,18.514532657212502],[-67.093752,18.515757],[-67.05297606966441,18.512073045833525]]
from_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:from_date], '%Y-%m-%d')
from_date = Time.utc(from_date.year, from_date.month, from_date.day)
to_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:to_date], '%Y-%m-%d')
to_date = Time.utc(to_date.year, to_date.month, to_date.day)

@coll = db.collection("points")
recordset = @coll.find(
    { 
        "$and" => [
            { "geometry.coordinates" => {
                "$within" => {"$polygon" => polygon}
            }}, 
            { "properties.time" => {
                :$gte => from_date,
                :$lte => to_date
            }}
        ]
    },
    :fields => { :_id => false }
)
```

Is there any way that I can group the results of all cities with a single query, or I have to query the database 78 times to get the count for each city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group), you need to use the [aggregation framework](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Aggregation-Framework-Examples). You will need an aggregation pipeline with two steps and an optional 3rd step:

1. The above query with a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator (by the way: the $and is unnecessary. You can put `"geometry.coordinates"` and `"properties.time"` in the same associative array)
2. a [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator which `_id => "$cityname"` (I guessed cityname is the field where the name of the city is stored) and `"number_of_points" => { "$sum" => 1 }`. The new field number_of_points will contain the number of points per city.
3. (optional) The name of the city will now be in the field _id. When you want the field to have a different name, you can rename it with an additional [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) step.

Comment: Actually the points inside the collection are not identified by city name, they only have the coordinates. Do you think it would be better to geocode each point before insertion to know which city they belong, then add a city name field to each point so I can group by cityname? Or there is a way that I can group by polygons(to avoid adding a cityname field)?. This is for a high traffic website, so performance is an issue.

Comment: @rcrivera That depends on your **exact** usage pattern, but when you need to calculate the city of each point more than one time (on average), then determining the city of each point once when you insert it would definitely be the more efficient solution. This assumes that your city limits do not change often (more often than points), because when a city limit changes all points around need to be reevaluated.